# How to get GUID of Lookup field for IOrg.associate in C#?

Tags: c#, sdk, microsoft-dynamics

I've tried to get the GUID of a record using a lookup field value

```
var installationSiteEntity = new Entity("csp_installationsite");
var serviceSite = installationSiteEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("cr3aa_servicesite");
```

Then I've used `service.Associate("account", serviceSite, servicesiteOpp, newCollection);`

But I get the error it can't convert string to guid, how do I get the GUID lookup value from this field?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting it as an entity reference

```
var serviceSite = installationSiteEntity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("cr3aa_servicesite");
service.Associate("account", serviceSite.id, servicesiteOpp, newCollection);
```

or covert the string back to a guid.

```
service.Associate("account", new Guid(serviceSite), servicesiteOpp, newCollection);
```

Comment: Neither works, both fail due to the line of var installationSiteEntity = new Entity("csp_installationsite"); saying Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes and that it returns as null

Comment: My error was using new Entity, I needed the var to hold what I had created in a loop elsewhere.